# Switching to another Minecraft version

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I switch to Minecraft 1.6.4 so I can be able to load world bioms for Minecraft 1.7.3/.4. I've looked up and tried a lot of thing but cant to seem to the solution. If anyone has an advice it would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. Are you asking if it's possible to play an earlier versionj but still have the new biomes?

Comment: no, i wanna play version 1.6.4 so i can load world bioms in order to switch to version 1.7.2

Comment: Switch from what?

Answer (score 3):

On the launcher, click edit profile. There should be a dropdown menu that says "use latest version". If you click that you can select any version, right down to alpha. Then click save profile and when you click play you will play the selected version.